# New IAM administrator user sees "You are not authorized to perform this operation"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am trying to get started with the AWS CLI on OS X. I installed `aws` via [pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_%28package_manager%29). I have created a new user in IAM and attached the pre-built *AdministratorAccess - AWS Managed policy* policy. Next, I have copied the generated Access Key ID and the Secret Access Key.

The user I created is not in any groups. Their policy looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Next, I ran `aws configure` from the command line, and entered the access key and secret key that I copied, plus a region code of `eu-west-1` (which seems unlikely to be relevant since IAM users are global), and an output format of `text`.

Then I have tried running a simple test command to set up a new group:

```
aws ec2 create-security-group --group-name my-sg --description "My security group" --debug
```

However, this fails with the following error:

> A client error (UnauthorizedOperation) occurred when calling the
> CreateSecurityGroup operation: You are not authorized to perform this
> operation.

Other commands fail in the same way.

My only theory is that it's a copy and paste error in the keys, but I've tried doing the whole process above twice and failed in the same way both times. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way I can debug which part of the process is failing?

Comment: When doing `aws configure` it's telling the AWS CLI which region to operate in. Users are global. But security group resources are specific to a region.

Comment: The error you are getting is not a copy/paste issue. It's a permissions error. The credentials you are using with the CLI does not have permissions to create security groups. If the access key/secret were bad, you would get another error.

Comment: After you applied the policy to your user, how long did you wait before executing the command? Sometimes it takes a few minutes for the permission changes to propagate through the system.

Comment: @MattHouser thanks! It's good to know that it's not a copy/paste error. I've just tried again after 15 mins and am still getting the same error.

Comment: Does your user require an MFA?

Comment: @MattHouser I don't know! But if I go to the IAM home page I see a few orange exclamation marks, including one about MFA... Could those be blocking the whole service?

Comment: No, those won't block the whole service. But if your particular user requires an MFA, then that may be blocking your commands.

Comment: Got it down to 2 orange exclamation mark warnings on https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home, still getting the same authentication error.

Comment: The only other things that I can think of are (a) your policy is not on your user (correct?) or (b) the access keys you're using are for a different user.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your AWS CLI is getting credentials from somewhere else. See [Configuration Settings and Precedence](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#config-settings-and-precedence)

Make sure it is not getting the credentials from environment variables or from other locations.
The AWS CLI looks for credentials and configuration settings in the following order:

- Command Line Options – region, output format and profile can be specified as command options to override default settings.
- Environment Variables – AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, etc.
- The AWS credentials file – located at ~/.aws/credentials on Linux, OS X, or Unix, or at C:\Users\USERNAME .aws\credentials on Windows. This file can contain multiple named profiles in addition to a default profile.
- The CLI configuration file – typically located at ~/.aws/config on Linux, OS X, or Unix, or at C:\Users\USERNAME .aws\config on Windows. This file can contain a default profile, named profiles, and CLI specific configuration parameters for each.
- Instance profile credentials – these credentials can be used on EC2 instances with an assigned instance role, and are delivered through the Amazon EC2 metadata service.

Comment: Yes, I had environment variables set. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 8):

In my case this was caused by not having the correct policy attached to the IAM user I was authenticating with.

Attach the `AmazonEC2FullAccess` policy to the user in the IAM Management Console and the command should work.

Comment: I did the same i'm able to do every  ops related to EC2, except spot request. I'm getting this error `You are not authorized to perform this operation`. Even though I've attached admin access to self still not able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not creating the security group in VPC, if this is the case you need to pass default VPC ID as a parameter.

Also try this with different regions:

```
aws configure set region <regions>
aws ec2 describe-security-groups
```

**NOTE: AWS has started providing default VPC's in most of the regions.**

Hope this helps and resolve your issue.

Comment: If this were the case, the error would be a bad request, not `UnauthorizedOperation`.