# Unable to load credentials using IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I got a problem using IAM roles.

I launched instances using Cloudformation template where i specified my role and policies to access s3 bucket and other amazon resources. After launching the script ***successfully*** fetches required resources from s3.

However I've launched my downloaded scripts that use boto3 as sdk and i got an error;  `Boto failed to load credentials` (as I understand it can load credentials either from aws credentials files or from IAM role.

Then I run `aws s3 ls` to check the problem and also got the same problem.  Also I tested my role using `policysim` (`S3ListAllMyBucketsnot`, `S3ListAllMyBucketsnot`) and figured out that everything is okay.

`Amazon S3ListBucketnot       required * allowed   1 matching statements.
Amazon S3ListAllMyBucketsnot required * allowed   1 matching statements.`

It should be noted that I've played around with cloudformation the whole day and launched pretty must instances (but shutdown them). Could it be a limitation issue?

Any solutions?

Comment: Do you have environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` set? Check my answer in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41621353/new-iam-admin-user-sees-you-are-not-authorized-to-perform-this-operation/41621987#41621987

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To confirm that the Role is correctly providing credentials to the Amazon EC2 instance, run this command on the instance:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/
```

It should show the name of the role assigned to the instance.

Then try this, inserting the role name:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/<ROLE-NAME>/
```

You should be presented with temporary credentials similar to this:

```
{
  "Code" : "Success",
  "LastUpdated" : "2017-04-26T16:39:16Z",
  "Type" : "AWS-HMAC",
  "AccessKeyId" : "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE",
  "SecretAccessKey" : "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY",
  "Token" : "token",
  "Expiration" : "2017-04-27T22:39:16Z"
}
```

If so, then `boto` will be able to automatically access those credentials.

Whenever something strange happens with `boto`, it's always a good idea to make sure it is updated to the latest version. This updates boto, boto3 and the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install boto --upgrade
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install boto3 --upgrade
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install awscli --upgrade
```