# AWS user with admin policy denied from CLI commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

**SETUP**

- I created a new aws user via the aws web console, and selected both console and programmatic/cli access
- I have added the `AdministratorAccess` policy directly to it.
- I have not enabled MFA for this user
- I have verified that my `credentials` file within the `aws` directory contains the proper values for `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key`
- I have verified that my `config` file within the `aws` directory does not contain any lines that would overwrite data for the profile
- I am verifying I am using the correct profile info by with `aws configure list`

**THE ISSUE**

- Executing `aws ec2 describe-regions` returns:

  `An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeRegions operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.`

The error is pretty straightforward, but I'm not sure what else I can do to authorize this user.  I had a coworker follow the same steps and the CLI worked as expected for him.

I researched the steps from [This S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41621353/new-iam-admin-user-sees-you-are-not-authorized-to-perform-this-operation) but am still scratching my head.

Comment: If you run `aws iam get-user`, does the Access Key exactly match the one showing in the IAM console for that IAM User?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein when running that command it doesn't seem to return the `aws_access_key_id`.  Only the `UserId`.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: That's fine. You'll see it also gives an `Arn` that identifies the entity that owns the credentials. Does the `Arn` match the user to whom you gave the `AdministratorAccess` policy?

Comment: Yes, the ARN matches root account/Administrator user.

Comment: Wait a second! Are you using the root account, or are you using an IAM User? They are different things.

Comment: Do any other AWS commands work, such as `aws s3 ls`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am using an IAM user, and so far no commands work.

Comment: But you said `aws iam get-user` worked. Do other IAM commands work (eg `aws iam list-users`? Can you determine what commands _do_ work and what commands _don't_ work?

Answer (score 0):

Your AWS CLI is getting credentials from somewhere else. See Configuration Settings and Precedence:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#config-settings-and-precedence

Make sure it is not getting the credentials from environment variables or from other locations. The AWS CLI looks for credentials and configuration settings in the following order:

Command Line Options – region, output format and profile can be specified as command options to override default settings.
Environment Variables – AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, etc.

1)**The AWS credentials file** –   ~/.aws/credentials on Linux, OS X, or Unix, or at C:\Users\USERNAME .aws\credentials on Windows. 
Can contain multiple named profiles in addition to a default profile.

2)**The CLI configuration file** – at ~/.aws/config on Linux, OS X, or Unix, or at C:\Users\USERNAME .aws\config on Windows. Can contain a default profile, named profiles, and CLI specific configuration parameters for each.

3)**Instance profile credentials** – these credentials can be used on EC2 instances with an assigned instance role