# AWS CLI connection AWS: "You are not authorized to perform this operation"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am following the course *[AWS Amazon Elastic Kubernetes Service Kubernetes masterclass devops microservices](https://www.udemy.com/course/aws-eks-kubernetes-masterclass-devops-microservices/learn/lecture/20857120#questions)*

As part of this, I have attempted to set the AWS configuration as:

```
aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [****************5P7N]:
AWS Secret Access Key [****************U3Hn]:
Default region name [eu-west-2]:
Default output format [json]:
```

`aws ec2 describe-vpcs` gives the response:

> An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeVpcs operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New IAM admin user sees "You are not authorized to perform this operation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41621353/new-iam-admin-user-sees-you-are-not-authorized-to-perform-this-operation)

Comment: What is the actual title of the course?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the permission AdministratorAccess to the IAM user.
I can now run aws ec2 describe-vpcs.